# Dismiss a series of UILocalNotifications or an alternative approach to achieve the same functionality

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uilocalnotification

I am building a small app that I can use to do Interval Training,
it schedules a series of `UILocalNotifications`, all scheduled at the same
time and all fired within a few minutes of each other.

The idea is that you put in your headphones and start a workout,
when you hear one kind of sound you rest and another kind of
sound you workout. I do this with localnotifications, it works
just fine. The reason for doing it like this and not just
having the app run with a timer is that I would like for
the Nike +iPod app to run in the foreground at the same time.

The notifications are just an alert and an OK button:

```
[notif setHasAction:NO];
```

So the idea is: Pop in the headphones, start my app, it schedules a series of notification - then start the Nike +iPod workout. When you hear the Notification sound, change from rest to workout or vice versa.

Ok, when the workout is over there are 15+ notifications on the screen and they need to be manually dismissed, this is a bit annoying and not at all user friendly.

**My question is now if there is a way to post only sound notifications? OR make sure earlier notifications are removed as new ones pop up OR is there a different/better way of going about achieving the functionality of getting a "sound indicator" while the app is in the background?**

Hope someone can lend a bit of experience or a good idea for an alternative:)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm how well this would actually work, but if you set the **alertBody** property on your UILocalNotification object to nil (this is the default value) when you create them, it should prevent an alert from appearing on screen as you fire them.

In addition, you might also want to set the **hasAction** property to NO, which prevents the user from seeing the action buttons (if you had an alert), or the slider (if they had the device locked).

But as for the actual stacked notification alerts - I don't believe there's any way to prevent them getting stacked.  That's something which might be worth raising a Radar for, so Apple could consider allowing that to happen in future iOS versions.

Comment: That was a super simple solution, setting the alertBody to nil:) I never thought that would work - but it does, just perfect! I know Apple does not encourage this as an alert sound without any visual representation is discouraged, but that is ok I just need it for my own workout and not for publishing in the App Store:) Thanks.